# Pandas groupby: date_from / date_to or date range get overlap intervals and prioritise them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, overlap

This is my sample df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'stage': 1, 'date_from': '2021-04-12', 'date_to': '2021-04-30'},
                    {'id': 1, 'stage': 2, 'date_from': '2021-04-05', 'date_to': '2021-06-13'},
                   {'id': 1, 'stage': 3, 'date_from': '2021-05-12', 'date_to': '2021-07-29'}])
df['date_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_from'])
df['date_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_to'])

print(df)
```

I have a big dataframe with entries markes by id. Each id can have multiple "stages" over time. As the sample df indicates these stages can overlap or even one can include the other.

The stages are different in their priority and the lower the stage the more important it is. That means stage 1 will always beat stage 2 and stage 3. Stage 2 will only beat stage 3 and stage 3 is only valid if no other stage is active at the same time.

Here is a visualisation of the wanted solution:
[image]

As I have no clue where to achieve this and additionally be very efficient I would be happy if someone could guide me / help me out with a solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Try (`stage_begin` is date when the stage begins):

```py
df["stage_begin"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x["date_from"], x["date_to"]), axis=1
)
df = df.explode("stage_begin")
df = df.sort_values(by=["stage_begin", "stage"], ascending=[True, True])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="stage_begin", keep="first")

df = df.groupby((df.stage != df.stage.shift()).cumsum()).agg("first")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       id  stage  date_from    date_to stage_begin
stage                                             
1       1      2 2021-04-05 2021-06-13  2021-04-05
2       1      1 2021-04-12 2021-04-30  2021-04-12
3       1      2 2021-04-05 2021-06-13  2021-05-01
4       1      3 2021-05-12 2021-07-29  2021-06-14
```

---

EDIT: To have `stage_end` (thanks @hpchavaz)

```py
df["stage_end"] = df["stage_begin"].shift(-1) + pd.Timedelta(-1, unit="D")
df["stage_end"] = df["stage_end"].fillna(df["date_to"].iloc[-1])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       id  stage  date_from    date_to stage_begin  stage_end
stage                                                        
1       1      2 2021-04-05 2021-06-13  2021-04-05 2021-04-11
2       1      1 2021-04-12 2021-04-30  2021-04-12 2021-04-30
3       1      2 2021-04-05 2021-06-13  2021-05-01 2021-06-13
4       1      3 2021-05-12 2021-07-29  2021-06-14 2021-07-29
```

Comment: May be adding `df['stage_end']=df['stage_begin'].shift(-1)+pd.Timedelta(-1, unit='D')`  and   `df['stage_end'].iloc[-1] = df['date_to'].iloc[-1]`

Comment: @hpchavaz I've added it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for this answer! How can I rewrite ```df = df.groupby((df.stage != df.stage.shift()).cumsum()).agg("first")``` to also group by ```id```? It can also happen that lets say id 1 ends with Stage 3 and id 2 starts with it. As far as I understand this code this will be grouped together, correct? 
Additionally the "stage_end" also needs to be done in a groupby!?

Comment: @AndrejKesely any hint on my question except the for loop that I came up with myself?